# how to rename all files under folder with specific extension name ( recursive approach )

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, rename, mv

we want to rename all files under /home/DB_home ( recursive )

so every file under DB_home will rename with .txt extension

example

before change

```
/home/DB_home/hg/ir/qemu-ga
/home/DB_home/td/glusterfs
/home/DB_home/yr/ew/sd/cv/ntpstats
/home/DB_home/yr/ew/sd/cv/proc.csv
/home/DB_home/td/GF.conf
/home/DB_home/td/tool.bin
```

example ( after rename )

```
/home/DB_home/hg/ir/qemu-ga.txt
/home/DB_home/td/glusterfs.txt
/home/DB_home/yr/ew/sd/cv/ntpstats.txt
/home/DB_home/yr/ew/sd/cv/proc.csv.txt
/home/DB_home/td/GF.conf.txt
/home/DB_home/td/tool.bin.txt
.
.
.
```

how to do it with find and mv ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that:

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} {}.txt \;
```

Comment: **Warning:** some implementations of `find` may pass `{}.txt` to `mv` as-is (either because it's not the first occurrence of `{}`, or because it's not just the two characters `{}`; see the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)). If this happens then all regular files below `.` will be moved to `{}.txt` one by one, so you will end up with one `{}.txt` containing data from the file processed last (note: one, not even "one per subdirectory"). If `find / -prune -exec echo {} {}.txt \;` prints `/ /.txt` then you can safely use this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . type f -exec mv {} {}.txt \;
```

... because nothing says you can use `{}` only once in the command, at least as long as you use the `;` and not the`+`.

Comment: "nothing says" – Actually the [POSIX specification of `find`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) states "if a *utility_name* or *argument* string contains the two characters `{}`, but not just the two characters `{}`, it is implementation-defined whether `find` replaces those two characters or uses the string without change" and "if more than one argument containing the two characters `{}` is present, the behavior is unspecified". This means there is probably at least one implementation of `find` that wouldn't replace `{}` in `{}.txt` in your code.

Comment: **Warning:** some implementations of `find` may pass `{}.txt` to `mv` as-is (either because it's not the first occurrence of `{}`, or because it's not just the two characters `{}`; see the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)). If this happens then all regular files below `.` will be moved to `{}.txt` one by one, so you will end up with one `{}.txt` containing data from the file processed last (note: one, not even "one per subdirectory"). If `find / -prune -exec echo {} {}.txt \;` prints `/ /.txt` then you can safely use this answer.